# msqli_fetch_array() doesnt work?

Tags: php, database

I have the following code:

```html
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'pruebatiendas');
mysqli_error($link); 
$que = "select * from categoria";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$que) or die(mysqli_error($link));
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-co">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>imagenes</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<a href="prueba.html"><?php echo $row['nombre_c']?></a><br/>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

but does not show me the links, What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried dumping the results to see if you have anything to begin with?

Comment: You do *no* error checking. How do you expect to figure out what's wrong if you don't look?

Comment: sorry for John Conde but I am new to programming php ...
In fact the posted code is fine, the problem I had was on the configuration, I solved when asked directly to a php programmer at my university.
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, that's what you need:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("pruebatiendas") or die(mysql_error());


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categoria") 
or die(mysql_error());



<?php

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "<a href='prueba.html'>".$row['nombre_c']."</a><br />";
}
?>
```